# How to get SID of each phone used in twillio notification API call

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am sending `SMS` to the list of million of phone numbers Through `twillio notification API`.
But I want to keep track about `SID` against each phone used. so that I can process it further for any phone number.
So what's the better way.
is there a way that allow me to get phone SID by providing phone number to the API.But again there will be issue that sometimes I send multiple messages to the same phone number.

How can I do this. As making `twillio` notification call to send bulk `sms` it does not return SID's of every number used in binding

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [statusCallback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages#monitor-the-status-of-your-message) in the Messaging Service Twilio Notify is using to get the Messaging SID's for each. Make sure your server infrastructure can handle the volume of webhooks Twilio returns to it.

[image]